# Using assertion to test the precondition

Tags: java

I am working on a school assignment, I am supposed to use assertions to test the preconditions of the deposit method and the constructor. I figured out the method, but I am stuck on how to add to the constructor.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
   A bank account has a balance that can be changed by 
   deposits and withdrawals.
*/
public class BankAccount
{  
   private double balance;

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.
   */
   public BankAccount()
   {   
      balance = 0;
   }

   /**
      Constructs a bank account with a given balance.
      @param initialBalance the initial balance
   */
   public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
   {   
      balance = initialBalance;
   }

   /**
      Deposits money into the bank account.
      @param amount the amount to deposit
   */
   public void deposit(double amount)
   {  
      assert amount >=0;

       double newBalance = balance + amount;
      balance = newBalance;
   }

   /**
      Withdraws money from the bank account.
      @param amount the amount to withdraw
   */
   public void withdraw(double amount)
   {   
      double newBalance = balance - amount;
      balance = newBalance;
   }

   /**
      Gets the current balance of the bank account.
      @return the current balance
   */
   public double getBalance()
   {   
      return balance;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is. Could you provide more information?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention what the preconditions where.  The deposit method requires that the amount deposited is at least zero.

Comment: Maybe "assert initialBalance >= 0;" in BankAccount's constructor?

Comment: Why are there four upvotes? I mean, I can see maybe one because it's sort-of complete, despite the actual question being MIA until the comments, but... come on.

Comment: @JoseM. Please go through this link for assertions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html You should not use assertion for arguments in public methods. Just go through it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
   Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.
*/
public BankAccount()
{   
   this(0);
}

/**
   Constructs a bank account with a given balance.
   @param initialBalance the initial balance
*/
public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
{   
    assert initialBalance >= 0;
    balance = initialBalance;
}
```

Creating any illegal `BankAccount` immediately results in an exception (if assertions are enabled).

Assertions can be placed practically everywhere in the code. They are for debugging purposes and will have no effect if you disable them (e.g. during production).

If the purpose of the bankaccount is to always be positive, you might want to add additional assertions, for example:

```
/**
   Withdraws money from the bank account.
   @param amount the amount to withdraw
*/
public void withdraw(double amount)
{   
    assert amount <= this.balance;

    this.balance -= amount;
}
```

Again, assertions are only for debugging, you should not try to catch them. Any assertion-exception indicates a fault in your program (or a fault in the assertion statement).

So the following should NOT be used:

```
try
{
    BankAccount newbankaccount = new BankAccount(5);
    newbankaccount.withdraw(6.0);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // illegal withdrawal
}
```

Instead, you should check the pre-conditions.

```
BankAccount newbankaccount = new BankAccount(5);
if (newbankaccount.getBalance() < 6.0)
{
    // illegal withdrawal
}
else
    newbankaccount.withdraw(6.0);
```

An assertion-exception should only fire if there is a logic error in your application.

Comment: I believe Assertion are not to be used to check parameters of public methods? I believe you have used it in withdraw() method.

Comment: They shouldn't, but they can always be used through the application to ensure correct functionality

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents on when to use [Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html);

When you use Assertions, please do not confuse it with the use for Exception.

- Use assertions when checking **pre-conditions, post-conditions and invariants of private/internal code**
- Use assertions to provide feedback to yourself or your developer team
- Use assertions when checking for things that are very unlikely to happen otherwise it means that there is a serious ﬂaw in your application.
- Use assertions to state things that you **know are to be true**.
- **Use Exceptions** when checking **parameters passed to public or protected methods and constructors**

## Please See this:

```
    public class BankAccount
    {  
        private double balance;

        /**
           Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.
        */
        public BankAccount()
        {   
            balance = 0;

            // assert is NOT used to validate params of public methods
            // if ( !isValidBalance(amount) ) {
            //     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Amount should be greater than zero.");
           // }

            //check the class invariant
            assert hasValidBalance(): "Construction failed.";

        }        
           // Implements the class invariant.
           // Perform all checks on the state of the object.
           // One may assert that this method returns true at the end
           // of every public method.

          private boolean hasValidBalance(){
              return balance>0;
          }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Bas has covered the important parts about assertions.  Basically, the will be skipped in production code, but can be enabled during debugging.

With that in mind, I would extend the behavior of your bank account code to actually use regular Java if statements; as it is always an error to deposit a negative amount (or to withdraw a negative amount).

Comment: thanks, I find the if statements easier, but the school assignment called for assertions.

Comment: @JoseM. Why easier? They're less verbose, and can be turned off. `if` statements might be more *flexible*, but they're really for a different purpose.

Comment: @DaveNewton, sorry that is what I meant to say, more flexible. I had no idea that I could use assertions instead of if statements to debug. This is a new concept for me. I normally write on VB and was I don't think there is something similar to assertions.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was wondering if you agree with the accepted answer. Since it has public methods and assertions have been used for the arguments, where the oracle docs say something else. Was just wondering if I am missing anything?

Comment: @JNL The OP is specifically tasked with using assertions, so this is a special case. The problem with assertions *instead* of exceptions is that they're normally turned off, so if something might go wrong in "real life", exceptions should be used. Assertions == internal and development, exceptions == real life/likely-to-happen.

Comment: @DaveNewton Totally agree on your point specified. Can you just check my answer posted and see if it satisfies OP's requirement. Just out of curiosity. Thanks.

Comment: @JNL The condition is wrong; 0 is a legal initial balance according to OP's comment. What's `amount` is in the ctor you show? There's no point in an assertion *after* the exception that would be thrown in this case; the point of the assertion is to ensure the amount *passed to the ctor* is >= 0, irrespective if this should be an exception (my opinion) or an assertion (OP's assignment). I'd write `hasValidBalance` as just `return balance > 0` (ignoring the incorrect logic), with the caveat that this may not be generally appropriate, since the original question is regarding the ctor only.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks Dave. I just wrote the Exception code to help the OP. Totaly understand, Assertion should'nt be after Exception. I will just comment that out, just to avoid future confusion. Appreciate it.